# Move Beginning of List Up To Index To Back in Python

Tags: python, list

Let's say I had a list:

[a, b, c, d, e, f]

Given an index, say 3, what is a pythonic way to remove everything before
that index from the front of the list, and then add it to the back.

So if I was given index 3, I would want to reorder the list as
[d, e, f, a, b, c]

Comment: Consider whether a list is the best choice. Depending on your needs a `collections.dequeue` or ringbuffer might be a more efficient data structure

Comment: You really don't want to do this to a big list, as they are implemented as contiguous arrays.  If you really need to do it, write a function to do it in place using a local variable as a storage register - you'll still end up with bonus refcounting, but won't end up with potentially tragic memory allocation patterns.

Comment: Good points, thankfully I know this list will be fairly short (less than 100 elements) so I figured it was no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the slice operation
e.g.,

```
  myList = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  myList[3:] + myList[:3]
```

gives

```
  ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> 
>>> l[3:] + l[:3]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

or bring it into a function:

```
>>> def swap_at_index(l, i):
...     return l[i:] + l[:i]
... 

>>> the_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> swap_at_index(the_list, 3)
['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(myList, x):
    return myList[x:] + myList[:x]
```

Should do the trick.

Call it like this:

```
>>> aList = ['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> print foo(aList, 3)
['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

*EDIT* Haha all answers are the same...

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way it's that's sdolan said, i can only add the inline way:

```
>>> f = lambda l, q: l[q:] + l[:q]
```

so, you can use like:

```
>>> f([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```